# Ticking Entity Error on Minecraft Server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-java-edition-server, server-administration

my server crashed today after me doing nothing much at all on it.

But every time I tried to start it again the same error occured directly after loading the world. I did not yet look into the minecraft code so I'm a bit new to it and I did not yet debuged a stack trace.

It seems to me that there is an Issue with the Chicken with `ID=30`. So I guess I just have to remove it from the world and everything will (hopefully) be fine.

So any help is appreciated. But If you dont really know what causes this issue, I would also really like to know how to manually remove that chicken. And why it has a passenger (Am I reading that correctly). And if you like point me to some debugging howto which might help with this issue.

Edit: Btw totally forgot this is a vanilla 1.11.1 server. No weird stuff at all running on it.

Edit: If I start the world with version 1.11 its not crashing but I obviously cant connect. I suspect this is a bug introduced in the update.

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// I blame Dinnerbone.

Time: 12/20/16 6:32 PM
Description: Ticking entity

java.lang.NullPointerException: Ticking entity
    at sn.al(SourceFile:1023)
    at sn.ak(SourceFile:1009)
    at sw.a(SourceFile:203)
    at sn.a(SourceFile:784)
    at sw.g(SourceFile:1585)
    at sw.n(SourceFile:1870)
    at sx.n(SourceFile:499)
    at sk.n(SourceFile:144)
    at ww.n(SourceFile:39)
    at wx.n(SourceFile:82)
    at sw.A_(SourceFile:1703)
    at sx.A_(SourceFile:282)
    at ajs.a(SourceFile:1517)
    at lw.a(SourceFile:718)
    at ajs.h(SourceFile:1495)
    at ajs.k(SourceFile:1378)
    at lw.k(SourceFile:551)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.D(SourceFile:634)
    at lh.D(SourceFile:335)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.C(SourceFile:562)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.run(SourceFile:466)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Thread: Server thread
Stacktrace:
    at sn.al(SourceFile:1023)
    at sn.ak(SourceFile:1009)
    at sw.a(SourceFile:203)
    at sn.a(SourceFile:784)
    at sw.g(SourceFile:1585)
    at sw.n(SourceFile:1870)
    at sx.n(SourceFile:499)
    at sk.n(SourceFile:144)
    at ww.n(SourceFile:39)
    at wx.n(SourceFile:82)
    at sw.A_(SourceFile:1703)
    at sx.A_(SourceFile:282)
    at ajs.a(SourceFile:1517)
    at lw.a(SourceFile:718)
    at ajs.h(SourceFile:1495)

-- Entity being ticked --
Details:
    Entity Type: minecraft:chicken (wx)
    Entity ID: 30
    Entity Name: Chicken
    Entity's Exact location: -328.71, 42.65, 146.03
    Entity's Block location: World: (-329,42,146), Chunk: (at 7,2,2 in -21,9; contains blocks -336,0,144 to -321,255,159), Region: (-1,0; contains chunks -32,0 to -1,31, blocks -512,0,0 to -1,255,511)
    Entity's Momentum: 0.00, -0.05, -0.07
    Entity's Passengers: [aao['Zombie'/31, l='worlds/premium welt', x=-328.76, y=43.05, z=145.99]]
    Entity's Vehicle: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
Stacktrace:
    at ajs.k(SourceFile:1378)
    at lw.k(SourceFile:551)

-- Affected level --
Details:
    Level name: worlds/premium welt
    All players: 0 total; []
    Chunk stats: ServerChunkCache: 625 Drop: 0
    Level seed: -4260957353016816717
    Level generator: ID 00 - default, ver 1. Features enabled: true
    Level generator options: 
    Level spawn location: World: (-172,64,295), Chunk: (at 4,4,7 in -11,18; contains blocks -176,0,288 to -161,255,303), Region: (-1,0; contains chunks -32,0 to -1,31, blocks -512,0,0 to -1,255,511)
    Level time: 124404153 game time, 128861290 day time
    Level dimension: 0
    Level storage version: 0x04ABD - Anvil
    Level weather: Rain time: 60178 (now: false), thunder time: 29363 (now: false)
    Level game mode: Game mode: survival (ID 0). Hardcore: false. Cheats: false
Stacktrace:
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.D(SourceFile:634)
    at lh.D(SourceFile:335)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.C(SourceFile:562)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.run(SourceFile:466)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.11.1
    Operating System: Linux (amd64) version 3.16.0-4-amd64
    Java Version: 1.7.0_111, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 773155432 bytes (737 MB) / 1029701632 bytes (982 MB) up to 1029701632 bytes (982 MB)
    JVM Flags: 2 total; -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 12, tallocated: 94
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    Player Count: 0 / 20; []
    Is Modded: Unknown (can't tell)
    Type: Dedicated Server (map_server.txt)
```

Comment: The stack trace can't tell if its modded or not. You sure there's nothing? Forge and other frameworks still count, even if you haven't loaded anything into them.

Comment: Yeah, Im pretty sure theres no mod running. I just downloaded the server executeable and run that one. Theres no mod folder and I dont see anything that looks like a mod in the server config. (I just host the server I didnt write the `server.properties` file). So If im mistaken please tell me where to look for mods?!

Comment: Huh. Where'd you download the executable from? Maybe it came as a package or something?

Comment: I got it from the [official site](https://minecraft.net/en/download/server)

Comment: Ok it seems to be a bug named [MC-111650](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-111650) introduced in Minecraft 1.11.1. Theres no fix yet.

Comment: Ok its fixed now in 1.11.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue (Bug [MC-111650](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-111650)) was fixed in [1.11.2](https://minecraft.net/en/article/minecraft-1112-released). The world is still playable after updating.

It affected all chunks where a zombie was riding a chicken and/or spider.